# How the main task is related to its sub tasks in task management apps?

Tags: task-management

I noticed in many task management apps that they provide sub tasks to the main task. However, when you complete these sub tasks the main task is not completed. You still have to tick it to complete it.

What scenario a main task should not be completed after its subtasks being completed?

Comment: Really?  Isn't that upto you?

Comment: This question is about software and not about the organisation of human work.

Answer (score 0):

- Integration/regression/review has not been completed to confirm all the subtask solutions play nicely with each other.
- Documentation has not been updated to reflect the overall task.
- Requester does not concur that the overall task is complete. There may be parts you missed when breaking it up, or there may be an edge case you didn't allow for, or...
- There may be work that didn't get handed off into a subtask. Sometimes breaking things off and s more trouble than just doing them inline.
- Et cetera.

Really, this separate approval is useful at some times for some people, and is at worst a minor nuisance to others. If you really want to manage things so tasks are done when all the subtasks are done, you can do so. But this gives you the flexibility to have higher-level provess s if you want them without having to explicitly manage all the dependency chains.

The tool is flexible. You and your team get to decide how to use it.

There's probably automation available which can close tasks when their subtasks are closed, if you *really* want that behavior. But I suspect that if you turned that on you would find yourselves adding a lot of "sanity check, did we forget anything" subtasks, negating the advantage.

(Afterthought: note that in Git, for example, subtask isn't the only relationship available. But folks may not realize that the other options exist, and they all have multiple uses depending on how you want to think about the work. A good tool supports multiple approaches.)